# How to find NaN in an array and stop once found?

Tags: arrays, fortran

Say, I want a routine to stop once a not-a-number is found in an array. How can I do this?

`if (array(i) .eq. NA) ...` seems not work.

The `array` is an array of floating point numbers:

`REAL :: array(35)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are really looking for `NaN`s and you have an up to date compiler then the `ieee_is_nan()` function should do the trick.  I think you'll need to `use ieee_arithmetic` or one of the other intrinsic IEEE modules.

If your compiler is not so new, it may have the commonly-implemented but non-standard `isnan()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You question is not very well constrained.  Is `array` an array of strings?  e.g.

```
character(len=20) :: array(40)
```

If this is the case, you should be able to just do:

```
do i=1,40
   if(array(i).eq."NA")then
       exit
   else
       !do something else
   endif
enddo
```

If this is an array of floating point numbers (and NA is defined to be some floating point constant), you might want to be careful as floating-point operations are rarely exact and rounding error can cause a calculation that would mathematically be equivalent to actually evaluate to different values.  In other words, the solution to this problem really depends on how `NA` and `array` are declared...

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. "array" is supposed to be an array of floating point numbers. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Lagrange -- But what is NA?  Is it a defined value?  Is it NaN?